# Will Identity fail if I assign roles and every time I use User.Identity.GetUserId()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

I want to create web portal, where there will be multiple users of 3-4 types. So I have created roles in Startup.cs Like

```
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        createRolesandUsers();
    }


    // In this method we will create default User & roles 
    private void createRolesandUsers()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));



        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            roleManager.Create(role);

            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = "1";
            user.Email = "a@b.com";
            user.ScreenName = "Ra";
            user.UserType = "Admin";
            string userPWD = "1";
            var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            if (chkUser.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Investor");
            }
        }
```

It creates Usertypes and on login page I give radio button to select own type. 
Now, suppose there are 4 roles.

1. Admin
2. Player
3. Coach

And suppose 10 people signup to site

2 people as admin 
4 people as player 
4 people as coach.

Now each one has it's type and user id. And if they log in, they can't access controllers of each other  due to Autorize attribute. But my question is, what about 4 players? Will they be ever able to access each others account? 
 They have same authorize rights  and they are authenticate too. How can I prevent users from same type to access each other's account ? 
I use " User.Identity.GetUserId() " on each page to get current user and I log all transactions by current id.

Comment: I'm not really sure about what you're asking here. Off course you won't be able to get data from another user unless you are logged in as that user, your queries return data from another user or you have been hacked. (I assume you log in through a password etc. and not via a login command on the server)

Comment: Thanks!  If I encounter any problem with this way, I'll extend this thread. My basic question was, what's the possibility that one user can access data of other user, as, he can access all other controllers he wants to. I am using routing mechanism to create unique url for everything depending on user, suppose my url is /controller/action/username/somerandomdigits now, if someone tries to use that url to get data from other user

Comment: You shouldn't be editing the url depending on the user. This is not user-friendly when an admin wants to pass a link to a certain part of your page to another admin for example. (as long as you're using User.Identity to query he will still have access to his own stuff even if it's another user in url) The User.Identity.GetUserId is stored in the background for as long as the session is open.

Comment: My project requirement is, they don't want ugly urls, they want all customized urls which are search engine friendly and even a user can remember it.

Comment: Then you should defenitly not include the username,... just something like something.com/controller/index, remember that your authorization attributes and User.Identity will be doing the work of getting the username and asking to login if needed, url should only contain the controller and the action in your page.  your code will look a bit like this: `public class Controller{ [AuthorizeRoles("Administrator")] public ActionResult Index{ return View(GetData(User.Identity.GetUserId())); ...`

Comment: Will that userId be in the URL ?

Comment: Nope, userdata is stored elsewhere. Once you are logged in you can access it in your code

Comment: Do I need to return (GetData(User.Identity.GetUserId()) everytime ?

Comment: Nope that is just example code for passing a model(data) to a view to display it. I used User.Identity.GetUserId() as a parameter to show that you can access User.Identity.GetUserId() here and change the data you send to your view depending on it.

Comment: Honestly speaking I am getting too much confused now, I am trying to do two things, one is migration and other one is security and url. None of it is working as I want :(

Comment: Maybe follow some tutorial about it or so? Take a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun) ? (haven't read it fully but I believe it should cover a lot of your problems)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Still I am not sure about that identity part. If you won't mind can we discuss about that if you have time and if you wish?