# Error: DataContext has been changed, even though I am not changing anything in mvc.net code first.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using code first to develop web application using mvc.net. 
I have added two fields to IdentityUser like this

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }

    public string UserType { get; set; }
}
```

I use this fields on my first controller

```
                UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                NewUserId = Genrate.GenrateUserId(),
                NewUserIdWithString = "Unspecified"
```

Apart from this, all application works fine but I don't know after adding this things, nothing works and it says, datacontext has been changed, may be there is/are another issue/s .

Answer (score 0):

You changed the database model by adding these two lines:

```
public string ScreenName { get; set; }
public string UserType { get; set; }
```

The database does no longer match your code and your application crashes.

It is however very easy to update said database to include these 2 new fields.
Go to the Package Manager console (bottom of VS in default layout) and type
`add-migration` The console will prompt you for a name for the migration. Fill in a name and next type `update-database` 
The first time you do this you might need to enter `Enable-Migrations` first

The database will then update to your new schema (note that it doesn't remove any present data and adds default values to non-nullable fields)

Comment: I have updated the migrations, but it doesn't work if I don't delete the migration folder. When I delete the migration folder application works.

Comment: You did not forget to update the database, right? Also if you view the user table in your database, do you see those 2 added fields present? The migrations folder should not cause any problems usually... Is there any new error coming up or so? like "no permission" when updating the database maybe?

Comment: Well, I guess there is no issue for this time being, I'll try to update some fields when required and try it again, thanks a lot !

Comment: If have time can you look at my another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881617/will-identity-fail-if-i-assign-roles-and-every-time-i-use-user-identity-getuseri  Sorry to ask that here

Comment: I tried to enable migration and update database but still it gives me same error. I have to delete migration folder each time

Answer (score 0):

You said that you delete the Migrations folder, you can't do it.

Migrations work with comparation, it compare the changes with the last migration, if you have no last migration, the new migration will be empty.

In order to solve that, do the following:

1. Comment the model;
2. Comment the lines you added to ApplicationUser;
3. Comment the new parameters that you added to register or another
   page;
4. Add new migration and update the database;
5. Uncomment all;
6. Add new migration and update database.

If you need to enable migrations: `Enable-Migrations`

To add new migration: `Add-Migration <string>`

To update the database: `Update-Database`